# CiviCRM Contributions page in iFrame on another domain

Tags: contribution-page

I have a contribution page in an iframe here
https://bit.ly/2ZunFB5

I get an error message when trying to make a payment

[image]

Yet, when I test the link on its own, it works perfectly.
https://bit.ly/3ntcEs1

Is there something I am overlooking? The contribution page is one one domain and the iframe is on a different domain.

Comment: is it browser related? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/using-iframes-to-present-contribution-page-on-remote-site